# React - Get the values of an object in different lines

Tags: reactjs, object, tooltip

I'm trying to get all the errors and place them inside a tooltip with this line: `Object.values(item.error)` and it works fine

[image]

The problem is the two errors are in the same line and I want every error to be in different line.

This is the code that is creating the tooltip. I'm passing props to the component `Tooltip`

```
{
  columnTitles.map((item, index) => (
    <th key={index} className="regular center" style={{ height: 80 }} >
      { item.error &&
        <Tooltip
          text={Object.values(item.error) || 'Error no especificado'}
          type="warning"
          element={
            <span className="color-dark-grey">&#x26A0;</span>
          }
        />
      }
      <span className="inline-block truncate h6 align-middle">
        {item.title}
      </span>
    </th>
  ))
}
```

And this is the `Tooltip` component, here I'm using the library 'react-tooltip':

```
class Tooltip extends PureComponent {
  render() {
    const { text, element, type, place } = this.props;
    return (
      <div data-tip={text} className="m0 p0">
        {element}
        <ReactTooltip
          type={type}
          place={place}
          effect="solid"
          className="tooltip-top"
          html
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

How can I make every error to be in a different line?

Comment: If their `text` prop can only accept a String, you might be hosed, however if it can accept a `node`, meaning a React element, you can do something like `text={Object.values(item.error).map(e => (<div>{e}</div>)}` to force a line break between the values.

Comment: @lux thanks for your comment, I think It can only accept string because when I added your code, it display `[object Object],[object Object]`

Comment: The docs look to support `multiline`.(https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tooltip). The author also seems to give an example here: https://github.com/wwayne/react-tooltip/issues/217